Unexpected behavior of os.path.join with leading slash
I've encountered a peculiar issue with os.path.join. When I add a forward slash (/) in front of the directory variable and pass it to os.path.join, the result is just /Test_directory. However, if I don't include the forward slash, the full path /home/mvnd3x/Desktop/Test_directory is printed. The same does not happens if I add a forward slash at the end of the parent_directory. Here’s the code I'm working with:
import os

directory = "/Test_directory"
parent_directory = "/home/mvnd3x/Desktop"
path = os.path.join(parent_directory, directory)

print(path)

Expected Output
/home/mvnd3x/Desktop/Test_directory

Actual Output
/Test_directory

Could someone explain why adding a forward slash in front of the directory variable or behind parent_directory variable causes this different behavior? How should I properly use os.path.join to avoid this issue?

I assume this is explained in the documentation of os.path.join, did you check it?

I tried reading it, but I couldn't understand it. Can you please explain it in simple terms?

As simple as possible: think of running cd on each argument in turn: cd /home/mvnd3x/Desktop followed by cd /Test_directory. What is your current directory then? From the doco, it seems pretty clear: "If a segment is an absolute path (which on Windows requires both a drive and a root), then all previous segments are ignored and joining continues from the absolute path segment.."
